# How do I draw an object that I always want to appear in the same place on screen on a scrolling orthographic camera using lib gdx?

Tags: libgdx

So I want to make an endless scroller game and the orthographinc camera is scrolling downward so i want the character to stay with the camera. I'm not sure how to aproach this i've been looking a lot online but couldn't find anything that works. The 2 ways I thought about doing it is to either make the object scroll at the same speed as the camera or in someway draw the object on the cameras "graph". This is the first game i'm making with libgdx so any help or suggestions are appreciated. :) Thanks

This is the gamescreen:

```
package com.ounceoftech.mygame;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;  
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;

public class GameScreen implements Screen
{
 OrthographicCamera camera;
 SpriteBatch batch;
 Vector3 touch;
 ship ship;
 Game game;

 public static int ship_x = 540 - 26;

 public GameScreen(Game game)
 {
    this.game = game;
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 1080, 1920);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    touch =new Vector3();
    ship = new ship();
 }
 @Override
 public void render(float delta)
 {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(255F, 255F, 0F, 1F);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    camera.position.y -= 5;
    camera.update();    
    generalUpdate(touch, camera);
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    //Rendering Code
    batch.draw(ship.image, ship_x, ship.bounds.y);
    batch.end();
 }
 public void generalUpdate(Vector3 touch, OrthographicCamera camera)
 {
    ship_x -= Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX() * 2;
    if(ship_x < 0) { ship_x = 0; }
    if(ship_x > 1027) { ship_x = 1027; }
 }
}
```

This is the object/player:

```
package com.ounceoftech.mygame;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;

public class ship
{
 public TextureRegion image;
 public Rectangle bounds;

 public ship()
 {
   image = Assets.spriteShip;
   bounds = new Rectangle(GameScreen.ship_x, 1600, 53, 256);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a new batch and draw the sprite on the position desired. Since this new batch has nothing to do with the camera, your sprite will be always at the same position.

Answer (score 0):

If you draw your "player" using screen coordinates, you will not have to project them. Screen coordinates range from (-1, -1, -1) to (1, 1, 1). (0, 0, 0) is the center of the Viewport and the coordinate system created by batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined).

Using screen coordinates, View, and Projection are Identity and, so, can be omitted. You can still transform your ship with a "World" matrix though, to move it around the screen. It sounds like you want its Y component to stay fixed, while allowing the user to change it's X. Although you are drawing to a 2D texture, there is still Z. If the interface is drawn at Z = 0 (front) and the scrolling map is drawn at Z = 1 (back), draw the ship at Z = 0.5 (behind interface but in front of map).

```
public static Matrix Identity;
public static int MaximumShipX = 1027;
public GameScreen(Game game)
{
...
Identity = Matrix4.idt();
}

@Override
public void render(float delta)
{
 batch.setProjectionMatrix(Identity);

 batch.begin();
 batch.draw(ship.image, ((float)ship_x / MaximumShipX) * 2.0f - 1.0f, 0.0f);
 //Y = 0.0f = vertical center of viewport
 //X component must be between -1 and 1
 //(float)ship_x / maximumShipX) ranges from 0 to 1
 //Multiplying by 2 and subtracting 1 moves the value into range
 //ship_x = 0, is now -1 instead (the left side of the viewport)
 //ship_x = maximumShipX, is now +1 instead (the right side of the viewport)
 //these are the same coordinates the camera matrix created previously
 batch.end();
}
public void generalUpdate(Vector3 touch, OrthographicCamera camera)
{
 ...
 if(ship_x > MaximumShipX) ship_x = MaximumShipX;
}
```

Comment: im getting an error with batch.setProjectionMatrix(Matrix.Identity);

Comment: i changed it to batch. getProjectionMatrix(); and that seems to work the player is staying on the screen now i just have to make sure tilt is working also i just set maximumshipx to 1 im not sure if thats right but now i have to figure out how to have a scrolling background and thanks the help!!! :)

Comment: updated code and deleted stale comments

Comment: Search for or ask a question about scrolling background and I will stop by.

Comment: What is "tilt"?

Comment: this is an android game so i use the accelorometer to move the x the of the player and as of right now im gettinga bunch of errors in my code haha man coding is a fun and frustrating and rewarding expierience lol thank god for people like you

Comment: so if i have identity = Matrix4(); i get errors but if i get rid of that and change public static matrix4 identity it works until i launch it then i get errors

Comment: now i just hit this suggestion and no errors 2batch.setProjectionMatrix(batch.getProjectionMatrix()); haha this is so confusing but the player is in the bottom left corner

Comment: I didn't read far enough; try Matrix4.idt()

Comment: batch.getProjectionMatrix()) will return Matrix.idt() if you have not yet assigned something else. Using batch.getProjectionMatrix() works, for now, but will not, later, if you have rendered another object that does need projection. Better to set projection to identity explicitly when using screen coordinates. Right now, you are "hoping" it is identity.

Comment: You need to scale the accelerometer output into a 0-1 range like I did with ship_x. Do it step-by-step, at first. Afterwards, just multiply it by maximumShipX and save it to ship_X!